# C++ Class Entanglement EDIT

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to use two classes' variables as to have access from class A's variables to class B's and vice versa. However, I can't figure a possible solution. It always ends up in either a loop, or the following error:

error: invalid use of non-static data member

Here's the code sample:

Player.h:

```
#ifndef _PLAYER_H_
  #define _PLAYER_H_

#include "Segment/Dynamic_Segment.h"

class Attributes_P;
class Player;

class Attributes_P : public Attributes_DS{
  protected:
  Player *rel;
  int inv_mcols, inv_mrows;

  public:
  Attributes_P();
  void controls( int MKEY_UP, int MKEY_RIGHT, int MKEY_DOWN, int MKEY_LEFT );
  void inventory( int inv_mcols, int inv_mrows );
};

class Player : public Dynamic_Segment{
  protected:
  int   **inv;

  public:

  int   MKEY_UP, MKEY_RIGHT, MKEY_DOWN, MKEY_LEFT;

  public:

  Player();
  Attributes_P set;
  friend class Core;
  friend class Attributes_P;

};
#endif
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Segment/Player.h"

Attributes_P::Attributes_P(){};

Player::Player() : Dynamic_Segment(){
  set.inv_mcols = 0;
  set.inv_mrows = 0;
}

void Attributes_P::inventory( int inv_mcols, int inv_mrows ) {
  this->inv_mcols = inv_mcols;
  this->inv_mrows = inv_mrows;
  &rel.inv = new int*[this->inv_mcols];
  for( int i = 0; i < this->inv_mrows; i++ ) {
    &rel.inv[i] = new int[this->inv_mcols];
  }
}

void Attributes_P::controls( int MKEY_UP, int MKEY_RIGHT, int MKEY_DOWN, int MKEY_LEFT ) {
  &rel.MKEY_UP = MKEY_UP;
  &rel.MKEY_RIGHT = MKEY_RIGHT;
  &rel.MKEY_DOWN = MKEY_DOWN;
  &rel.MKEY_LEFT = MKEY_LEFT;
}
```

Have been banging my head against a wall for some time now... Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: It's generally not very wise to do two-way interactions. It would be better to just provide a *callback*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I see. I think it's

```
&rel.
```

should be

```
rel->
```

i.e.

```
rel->MKEY_UP = MKEY_UP;
```

Did you mean `(*rel).MKEY_UP`? This also works.

Comment: @LuchainGrigore No, I did what's above, declared it as a pointer and used its address, utterly silly to forget how to refer to a pointer member's function. Have been working for a day and can't think now >.< Again, thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: @LuchainGrigore Now I get a segmentation fault. Debugging it with gdb, it stops just about at e.g. rel->MKEY_UP = MKEY_UP;

Comment: @user203432 `rel` is probably invalid then. Did you initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: Now, after I did, only errors are it looks in the parent for those variables, not in class Player